# Capistrano or Fabric like tool for Javascript programmers

Tags: automation

I am a javascript engineer, and looking to automate my application deployments (nodejs) to AWS. Are there any good javascript-based tools for this?

Fabric and Capistrano are python and ruby-based

Answer (score 0):

The only tool I was able to find was launch (https://github.com/bengourley/launch) which hasn't been updated for 2 years, so probably isn't very stable.